# Why spring security oauth2 client need AuthorizationRequestRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am having a problem while applying spring oauth2 client.

I found that `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` wants to create an `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` and store it temporarily via `authorizationRequestRepository`.

Related code:

```java
// OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
    OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
    ...
    this.sendRedirectForAuthorization(request, response, authorizationRequest);
    ....
}

private void sendRedirectForAuthorization(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {
    ...
    this.authorizationRequestRepository.saveAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest, request, response);
    ...

}
```

It is stated in the document that the default implementation is to store it in an HttpSession and may be used to store it in a cookie if desired.

Related document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-authorization-request-repository

### Question)

But I do not understand. Why should not the `authorizationRequest` object be stored in memory? 
I do not know why spring security provide the `AuthorizationRequestRepository` interface so I can use Session or Cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store it for future requests because you don't want to perform OAuth flow on every request.

Answer (score -1):

If you are developing a react SpringBoot application. You might need store some data like the react app url where the SpringBoot will redirect to after successful or fail authentication.